# Can I get into configuration mode by command "config" instead of "configure terminal"?

Tags: switch, router, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I would like to ask: When I configure router or switch in for example Putty, can I get into configuration mode by command "config" instead of "configure terminal"? Or I need to use "configure terminal" always?

```
enable
configure terminal
interface Gi0/0/0
```

```
enable
config
interface Gi0/0/0
```

Comment: No, but most people do something like `conf t`.

Answer (score 1):

For most versions of IOS, you need to add the keyword `terminal` because there are several configuration options.  You can see them if you type `config ?`:

```
router#config ?
  confirm            Confirm replacement of running-config with a new config file
  memory             Configure from NV memory
  network            Configure from a TFTP network host
  overwrite-network  Overwrite NV memory from TFTP network host
  replace            Replace the running-config with a new config file
  revert             Parameters for reverting the configuration
  terminal           Configure from the terminal
  <cr>               <cr>
```

Answer (score -1):

`config t` works fine when i used it last time in PT

Comment: "config t" sorry should write it more clearly

Comment: Yes, config t(erminal) is one of the options.

Comment: @TheDavemedia9112 Whether it works or not wasn't the question, and PT wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Well the "answer to the question" is a single word: NO.